# how to inherit from a custom theme in liferay

Tags: themes, liferay

For example, Firstly, I created a customized theme which inherits from '_style', this is called 'theme1'. then I would like to create another theme which inherits from 'theme1'. Is that possible? if so, how it works behind the scene?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've described this problem in [this blog article](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/theme-development%3A-choosing-your-parent) for Liferay 6.0, should still work for newer releases.

Answer (score 1):

your question intrigued me so i tried to search a solution, however the result is not completely satisfactory, i explain what i found:

1. I created a new `inherit-theme` plugin project, when he asked me the parent theme i left the default choice (`_styled`)
2. Go on `inherit-theme/build.xml` and change `<property name="theme.parent" value="_styled" />` with `<property name="theme.parent" value="my-custom-parent-theme" />`, where `my-custom-parent-theme` is a precedent project theme that i developed.
3. Try to save and you can see in console an error like this (more or less):

   ```
   file not found: C:\myPc\...\inherit-theme\my-custom-parent-theme\build.xml
   ```
4. He search for the `build.xml` of the parent in himself, so i tried to copy/paste the entire parent project inside the child.
5. Build the `inherit-theme` and surprise ! It works ! The CSS, JS and template files are copied into their respective folders.

But in my opinion this is not a nice solution, it is little more than a manual copy of every single file, furthermore the resulting project is heavy because it has to contain the entire parent and at least the first build/deploy is pretty slow... on the other hand it is possible that a better solution doesn't exist.

Conclusion:
I don't know how many benefits it can bring, this test was pretty fast and maybe there will be problems continuing development.

All the test was on Liferay 6.2

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

What it does is at build time it takes the parent-theme (`theme1`) files and creates your new theme. So if you have changed say the `portal_normal.vm` in your `theme1` then while building your theme it would take the updated `portal_normal.vm` in your child-theme. So now you can work on the updated `portal_normal.vm` if you want to change it further. Similarly it will take every other file like the JS and CSS from the parent theme.

So the inheriting is but at build time and not at run-time as you might have thought.

Hope this helps.